# FreeBSD won't load my keymap

Tags: terminal, freebsd, keyboard-layout

I successfully installed FreeBSD 12 in a VM. While installing, the installer asked me what keyboard layout I want, so I selected "Czech (QWERTZ, accent keys)". After I was done, I rebooted the system and logged in but after typing something, I found out that the keyboard layout wasn't set.

Fine, so I ran `kbdmap` and selected my keyboard layout again, but to no avail. Even after relogging, it still uses the default (US, I presume) keyboard layout.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The keymap should be specified in `/etc/rc.conf`. For e.g.

```
keymap="cz.iso2"
```

Quoting the `rc.conf` man page

> keymap      (str) If set to “NO”, no keymap is installed, otherwise the
>                    value is used to install the keymap file found in
>                    /usr/share/syscons/keymaps/⟨value⟩.kbd (if using syscons(4))
>                    or /usr/share/vt/keymaps/⟨value⟩.kbd (if using vt(4)).

Reference: [rc.conf](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?rc.conf(5)) man page

Comment: This does not work either. It just ignores it.

Answer (score 0):

So, it took me a long time to realize, but when you select "Czech (QWERTZ, accent keys)", everything is working. This specific keymap has actually two keymaps: English and Czech. When you look at the keymap file (`/usr/share/vt/keymaps/cz.kbd`), you can see:

```
...
# English/Czech keyboard lock:  (Left)Alt+Shift
...
```

So press <kbd>(Left) Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd> to switch from English to Czech layout.